# How to pass a file as an argument to php exec?

Tags: php, c, exec, command-line-arguments

I would like to know how I can pass the content of a file (csv in my case) as an argument for a command line executable (in C or Objective C) to be called by exec in php.

Here is what I have done: the user loads the content of its file from an URL like this:

```
http://www.myserver.com/model.php?fileName=test.csv
```

Then the following code allows php to parse and load the csv file:

```
<?php

$f = $_GET['fileName'];
$handle = fopen("$f", "r"); 

$data = array(); 
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) { 
$data[] = $line;
}

?>
```

where I'm stuck is how to pass the content of this csv file as an argument to exec. Even if I can assume the csv is known to have only two columns, how many rows it has is user-specific, so I cannot pass all the values one by one as parameters, e.g.

```
exec("/path_to_executable/model -a $data[0][0] -b $data[0][1] .....");
```

The only alternative solution I guess would be to write something like that:

```
exec("/path_to_executable/model -fileName test.csv");
```

and have the command line executable do the csv parsing, but in that case, I think I need to have the csv file physically written on the server side. I'm wondering what happens if several people are accessing the webpage at the same time with their own different csv file, are they over-writing each others?

I guess there must be a much proper way to do this and I have not figured it out. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: what's the valid parameter input can be supplied to the executable file?

Comment: It can be more or less anything because I code the executable. Possibilities I thought were either the csv file name or values one by one if I knew the csv size.

Comment: by `one by one` is it equal to `line by line`?

Comment: No, not line by line but value by value. The csv contains two times series organized by columns. Each row is a different year. I can either pass the first time series and then the next one, or pass the values for the two time series for the first year, and then for the second year and so on. The command line executable will take care of this properly.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [popen()](http://php.net/popen) to get a handle on the process to write to. If you need to go both ways (read/write) and might requre some more power, have a look a [proc_open()](http://php.net/proc_open).

You could also just write your data to some random file (to avoid multiple users kicking each other's race-conditioned butts). Something along the lines of

```
<?php
$csv = file_get_contents('http://www.myserver.com/model.php?fileName=test.csv
');
$filename = '/tmp/' . uniqid(sha1($csv)) . '.csv';
file_put_contents($filename, $csv);
exec('/your/thing < '. escapeshellarg($filename));
unlink($filename);
```

And since you're also in charge of the executable, you might figure out how to get the number of arguments passed (hint: argc) and read them in (hint: argv). Passing them through line-based like so:

```
<?php

$csvRow = fgetcsv($fh);
if ($csvRow) {
  $escaped = array_map('escapeshellarg', $csvRow);
  exec('/your/thing '. join(' ', $escaped));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess that before writing the file on disk, I would need to check that it is a proper csv file and not just any file with a csv extension? Or is it irrelevant because of unlink just immediately after?

Comment: are you afraid of temporarily storing a virus or some such in your /tmp, or are you afraid of the csv being in a wrong format? if the former is the case, your executable would fail and the file would be removed immediately thereafter. If you're afraid of a wrong format... you should know that CSV comes in a ton of ugly flavors. You'll need to know field- and line-delimitors, quote- and escape-characters (and the encoding!) anyways.

Comment: If the user can input an url, yes, they can download whatever they want. If you allow that, it's up to you to check what's coming in. But, I'd be more worried about huge chunks of data (say, anything above 2MB per file, and more than 100 files concurrently). ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having that data on disk, and loading it within the command line utility - it is much less messing about. But if you can't do that, just pass it in 1 (unparsed) line at a time:

```
$command = "/path_to_executable/model";
foreach ($fileData as $line) {
  $command .= ' "'.escapeshellarg($line).'"';
}
exec($command);
```

Then you can just fetch the data into your utility by looping `argv`, where `argv[0]` is the first line, `argv[1]` is the second line, and so on.